# Changing position of a gui with a foreach loop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, foreach, rect

so I am programming a scorelist and wanted all scores to be listed in a GUI.
I have a `string[]` with all scores so I used a

```
foreach(string score in scores) { 
y = y + 60f;
GUI.Label(new Rect(0, y, 100, 20), score); 
}
```

But now every GUI.label gets moved, not only the new ones. So if it's at the 3rd score for example, every object is at 180f.

Comment: What i can suggest to you is, you should use [UI](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui) . Its been a while since i've used GUI, but i think your problem is you do not have a reference for you NEW `GUI.LABEL` which is created for your new score. All of your indiviual score should have a `GUI.LABEL` right?

Comment: Yes, I wanted them to be like a list, so the score then distance and the new score. I also wanted a GUI.box arround each score.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Text` component to display texts on the screen. Avoid anything that requires `GUI.Label` or the `OnGUI` function. You can learn more about Unity's UI [here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui).

To answer your question, you can use **multiple** `Text` components to show each value in the string array with the help of the [`Horizontal Layout Group`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-HorizontalLayoutGroup.html) and the [`Layout Element`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-LayoutElement.html) components. You can lean how these work by just Googling them.

OR

You can also use **one** `Text` component in combination of "`\r\n`" and then concatenate and display all the strings to that one `Text` component. The "`\r\n`" is used to move each text to a new line.

```
public Text textScore;
public string[] scores;

void Start()
{
    textScore.horizontalOverflow = HorizontalWrapMode.Overflow;
    textScore.verticalOverflow = VerticalWrapMode.Overflow;


    foreach (string score in scores)
    {
        //Add new Score
        textScore.text = textScore.text + score;
        //Add new Line
        textScore.text = textScore.text + "\r\n";

        //OR (Do both one one line)
        //textScore.text = textScore.text + score + "\r\n";
    }
}
```

If you want more spaces between each text, you can add as many "`\r\n`" as you want in each loop. For example, `textScore.text = textScore.text + score + "\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n";`.